# How can I clicked with [routerLink] inside a child view to another child view?

Tags: angular, typescript, router

I have a small problem with a view from my website in Angular, because I'm trying to move from a child's view to another child's view in my application. When I've clicked on a button with the `routerlink`, it takes me to the view, but the problem is that the view goes dark and I can't do anymore until I refresh with `f5` or the reload `button` from my web navigator.

**ROUTES**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path:'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path:'administrator',
    component: AdministratorComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children:
    [
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
      { path: 'information', component: InformationComponent },
      { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
      { path: 'letter', component: LetterComponent },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: "/error"
  }
];
```

This is the model of my webpage:

[image: Model Page]

And trying to access to my children view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" [routerLink]="['/administrator/letter']">
    Check
</button>
```

> **Note:** If I access from the `AdministratorComponent` it works just like I'm wating for, but in this case I need another way to make it.

How can access correctly to that view?

Comment: Try [routerLink]="['letter']"

Comment: No, I tried that and it takes me to error component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to delete this question, because this bug or mistake can happen to anotherone. In this case I've forgotten to say that in the view I'm using a modal window, so the class of the modal window to access the other secondary view remains activated (which obscures the view that is being accessed)

Just like this:

[image: Bootstrap's class]

Ok, how can solve this?

Just you need to use an attribute to close the modal: `data-dismiss`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" [routerLink]="['/administrator/letter']">
   Check
</button>
```